# What does class << self mean?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Regarding:

```
class Test
  class << self
    def hi
      puts "Hi there"
    end
end
```

I came up with following image in my head:

Since everything is an object in Ruby, classes themselves are objects of class `Class`. By calling `class << self` you open up `Class` definition from the inside of `Test` and inject few instance methods. Since `Test` is an instance of `Class`, you can call those methods same way you call instance methods on your objects: `Test.hi`.

Following is the pseudo code which helps to visualise my previous sentence:

```
class Class
    def hi
        puts “Hi there”
    end
end

Test = Class.new(class Test
end)
Test.hi
```

Am I getting this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose we have an object `obj` of class `A`. At this point, the ancestor hierarchy of `obj`'s class is:

```
[A, ...]
```

What `class << obj; ... end` does is that it creates a class `B` whose only instance is `obj`, and puts it in the ancestor hierarchy of `obj` so that the ancestor hierarchy of the `obj`'s class becomes:

```
[B, A, ...]
```

If you write `class << self; ... end` within the context of `Test`, then the body of it will be a class whose sole instance is `Test`. If you define an instance method `hi` within that body, then that will apply to instances of that class, which is `Test`. Hence you will be able to do `Test.hi`.

Comment: So what you are saying is basically instead of modifying `Class`, Ruby creates an anonymous class, which inherits from `Class` and has `hi` method defined, and is class of `Test` object?

Comment: Nice to finally crack this. Thank you!